# Related js files and css files of html block

Tags: javascript, css

how to find the **Related** JavaScript and Style-sheet file(s) of a html block.
i want to split the html blocks in different pages, every block has its own JavaScript and Style-sheet file(s). how i can split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, Google Chrome/Firefox Code Inspector will tell you which styles and events are attached to DOM elements, so you could, with some manual work split your code, but it will not tell you EXACTLY which CSS/JS is related to